# Как найти в текстовом файле слово из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список: `['hello', 'my name', 'is', 'Aleksey']`
Имеется файл:

```py
my_open_file = open('hello.txt', 'r')
```

; в файле строки идут с абзацами:

```
привет
меня зовут
алексей
hello
как дела
my name
```

Необходимо определить используется ли слово из списка в файле и показать через `print()` какое слово используется

Сейчас выводится: `[]`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: прочитать файл в переменную, проверить по очереди наличие слова в переменной, вывести, если наличествует

Comment: Я логику понимаю, мне бы помочь именно с кодом)

Comment: ну уж нет, тут так не работает. Начинай писать код, когда будет конкретные вопросы, то задавай. А говорить "помочь с кодом" имея в виду "написать вместо меня" тут не прокатывает.

Comment: в принципе, по любому вопросу, который может возникнут при написании кода для этой задачи, на этом сайте есть ответы и даже не один

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена))
Решением оказалось просто удалить '\n'
Может будет кому полезно:
Код:

```
list = ['hello', 'my name', 'is', 'Aleksey']
my_open_file = open('hello.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')
combine = set(my_open_file)
print([a for a in combine if a in list])
```

Comment: ``split('\n')``, кстати, не удаляет ``\n``, а делит строку по этому символу на список строк.

Comment: Странное решение. Для чего `[a for a in combine if a in list]`, если работаете с множествами? Достаточно применить `intersection()` или `&`

Comment: Я недавно вообще принялся за Python, поэтому какое решение пришло в голову, такое и реализовал)

Answer (score 1):

Супер, что разобрались, несколько замечаний

1. Читать файл лучше использовать
   [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)-директиву

   ```py
   with open('hello.txt', 'r') as file:
       lines = file.readlines().split("\n")
   ```

   Очевидно, что в вашем коде после чтения вы не закрыли поток. С
   директивой `with` этого делать нет необходимости, все автоматически
   закроется.
2. Не используйте имена переменных, которые зарезервированы. То есть название `list` не корректно, используйте `list_` если хотите так называть переменную. Лучше выбрать более понятное название `search_set` или `set_of_words`
3. Как вам указали в комментарии, можно использовать пересечение множеств, и не работать с генератором, как у вас

   ```py
   result = list(set(my_open_file) & set(list_))
   ```
4. Ничего плохого в генераторе нет, но тогда можно убрать приведение переменной `my_open_file` к типу данных `set`. И работать просто со списками, которые тоже являются итерируемыми.